# How can I access Android private API's which doesn't exposed in TelephonyManager?

Tags: android, telephony, telephonymanager

I intend to write tests related to the Phone and Direct SIM write.

What are the alternatives in case the required APIs aren't exposed in TelephonyManager but exist as private APIs in `PhoneBase.java`, `PhoneFactory.java` or `CommandInterface.java`?

Specifically, my questions are:

1. What is the "replacement" for: `PhoneFactory.getDefaultPhone()`?
2. What is the alternative in order to access the `CommandsInterface` (e.g.: `CommandsInterface mCmdIf = ((PhoneBase)mPhone).mCM`)?

Thanks in advance,
Micha

Comment: The internal API calls in PhoneFactory that Micha is referring to [can be viewed here](http://hi-android.info/src/com/android/internal/telephony/PhoneFactory.java.html).

Answer (score 6):

You can use `java reflection`.

Here is how I accessed methods of  `com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony` class to block an incoming call ...

```
private void endCall() throws Exception {
      TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

      Class<?> c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
      Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
      m.setAccessible(true);
      ITelephony telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(tm);

      telephonyService.silenceRinger();
      telephonyService.endCall();
      Toast.makeText(context, "Call Ended !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: I have a similar question and it seems you know the answer. Could you please look at my telephony/reflection question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43859456/how-to-use-reflection-to-get-accurate-lte-pci-physical-cell-id-in-android-app